# Delete a dataframe completely like it has never existed

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

The df.unpersist() method doesn't satisfy my need. I need to remove the dataframe completely from the Kernel session so when I rerun my code in development I don't need to restart Kernel every time in order to erase the dataframe.

Comment: What is your Spark version? Maybe it has something to do with this? https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-24889 If you just need to remove the var you may consider simplu `del df`.

Comment: My Spark is version 3.0.0.
```del df``` did exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 2):

`del df` deletes the dataframe like it never existed.